# Mono mac packager doesn't work with gdiplus.dll

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I am making a desktop app with MonoMac that relies on system.drawing. This works fine within MonoDevelop, but the created .app package doesn't.

I get this exception:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: gdiplus.dll
```

Now, there are many references to this particular problem around the web, one of the more recent ones here: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3263.

However, I have been unable to get it working. I can copy libgdiplus.dll.dylib from the lib folder into the MonoBundle folder of my app which gets me a bit further. Setting MONO_LOG_LEVEL to debug now tells me this:

```
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'dlopen([app]/Contents/MonoBundle/libgdiplus.dll.dylib, 9): Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/libglib-2.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: [app]/Contents/MonoBundle/libgdiplus.dll.dylib
  Reason: image not found'.
```

I've copied libglib-2.0.0*.dylib in there as well. This doesn't help because it's searching in the Library/Frameworks/... folder. I've tried to add a dllmap entry both to the config file in the MonoBundle folder, as well as in a libgdiplus.dll.dylib.config file (and libgdiplus.dll.config). These seem to be ignored because I keep getting that same error.

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably suggest switching to using MonoMac.CoreGraphics instead of System.Drawing as the best solution. WinForms APIs weren't really considered for MonoMac apps (other than System.Drawing.Color and System.Drawing.RectangleF, and SizeF).

Could you submit a bug report about this to http://bugzilla.xamarin.com? Either I or Sebastien will need to look into ways to solve this problem in the long-term. I can't promise how long you might have to wait for a solution, though, so you really should consider using CoreGraphics.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I'll look into CoreGraphics then.